# Ignoring Particular Fields Using Room on Android

Tags: android, database, sqlite, orm, android-room

Having Room used in Android app, I created entity objects as required. Also, having decoupled layered architecture, I use Room entities only in data layer, converting them further to domain objects to be used in use case and UI layers.

Now, the problem is following:

Room provides us with very convinient way to to CRUD operations with simple anotating methods and providing Entity object.

But, how can we achieve that when Entities (and DB tables) have some meta data fields that are used only in db layer, and I don't map them to domain objects.

Here is an example of two simple classes from different layers (without annotations, for convenience):

```
data class CarDbEntity(id: Int, brand: String, color: String, _createdAt: Long, _someOtherMeta: Int)
data class CarDomainObject(id: Int, brand: String, color: String)
```

Now, I have convertors from DbEntity to DomainObject classes. But it cannot be done vice versa, since I am not mapping _metaFields to DomainObjects. Which means, since I cannot properly recreate DbEntity class, I cannot use convinient ways of crudding like this:

```
@Update
fun updateCar(car: CarDbEntity)
```

So, if I want to update car brand name or color, I need to write manually custom `@Query` with SQL for each case I need it.

I even tried creating `CarWithNoMetaDbEntity` trying to attach it to the same table as `CarDbEntity`, hoping that it would update just fields that exist in that class (and leave _meta as it is) but Room doesn't allow multiple entity classes bound to the same table.

Is there any technique where I can achieve updating such objects easily, without writing bunch of update SQL queries?

Comment: "since I am not mapping _metaFields to DomainObjects" -- why not? "Is there any technique where I can achieve updating such objects easily, without writing bunch of update SQL queries?" -- I think that the "target entity" feature of Room 2.2.0 is designed for your use case: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/room#2.2.0-alpha01

Comment: First - why I am not mapping meta data to domain objects? Because, I don't need them there. Don't want to clutter objects with unnecessary data, especially sincy my domain model is not 1-to-1 replicated database structure.

And second, related to my questions, yes, target entities is something that might solve my problem. Will try it later certainly and get back. Thanks.

Comment: So, Room 2.2.0 is currently available only in alpha at this moment, which is not something I'd use in my app. Also, I have tried it, to see how it works, and updated my Room in gradle to 2.2.0-alpha01, but it seems that it doesn't have targetEntity implemented yet. Tough luck. Still, goot to know that they have plan for making this work.

Comment: "it seems that it doesn't have targetEntity implemented yet" -- that's odd. It is listed in the `2.2.0-alpha-01` release notes. You might consider filing a bug report. But yes, depending on your anticipated app release timing, Room 2.2.0 might not ship in final form before you need it.

Comment: Ok, I digged little bit. Instead of targetEntity, there is @Update param called just entity, that didn't exist before 2.2.0-alpha01. And it's javacode says that it is something like targetEntity described on the web page, _but_, instead of table name it expects Class reference to original entity class. So, feature is kinda there, just the code and docs are not in sync. Still, I have some problem compiling it at this moment, but working on it.

Comment: Ok, it works. The thing is that for some unknown reason, fields in partial Entity should be writable also, so instead of val they needed to be declared as vars. Why does it need to write into my partial Entity? Don't know, it doesn't sound reasonable.